# resultSizeEstimate is completely wrong

Tags: gmail-api

I've got a problem with the Gmail API and the `resultSizeEstimate` field of the `messages.list` method.

The value is completely wrong : if I query all of the messages of `INBOX` using `https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?labelIds=INBOX`, I got a resultSizeEstimate of `51`, even if I can fetch more than `51` messages at once with `maxResults`.

The thing is that I've got more than 8k messages in my inbox, if I look in the Gmail GUI or using the `labels.get.messagesTotal` field.

That's not a problem if I want to have the total number of messages in a label since `labels.get` works fine, but how can I do to have the total number of messages of a specific query ? If I add a `&q=...` to my `messages.list` request, I still have a value of max results around `50`, which is obviously wrong.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

`resultSizeEstimate` is just that, an estimate. You should probably not use it if it has to be a very close estimate.

You can't get the total amount of results of a query. You have to [list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) until there is no `nextPageToken` in the response. Then you know you have gotten every result of the query.

Comment: I think that 51 instead of 8k is a pretty bad estimate. In the Gmail GUI we can see the count of search results, how can I do the same ? Counting each page one by one is not the most efficient, there has to be another way

Comment: @natinusala Yeah, I've been in the same boat as you, and it's infuriating. I think there is an issue in Google's tracker for this problem.
What you could do in the mean time is just showing `99+ results` for a query if the first page is full. That is enough for many use cases.

Comment: Mine showed 237 as an estimate, 61000+ messages. I do not even retrieve that field anymore, it is useless.